# Predicate logic example..

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I've got this predicate symbol:

$(\forall x R(x,y)) \implies (\forall y Q(x,y))$

$R=\{(x,y) \in Q \times Q \hspace{0,2cm}|\hspace{0,2cm} x<y\}$

$Q=\{(x,y) \in Q \times Q \hspace{0,2cm}|\hspace{0,2cm} x=y\}$

Universum is Q

Valuation: $v(x)=-2 \\ v(y)=\frac{3}{5} \\ v(z)=0$

I am not sure, if I understood this rightly.

First part of predicate:
$(\forall x R(x,y))$

- $x$ is bound variable
- $y$ is free variable, so I must use valuation $v(y)=\frac{3}{5}$
- in my case it is mean: **for all rational numbers applies, that they all are less then $\frac{3}{5}$** -> it is **false** because for example 10 is from $Q$ and it is greate then $\frac{3}{5}$

Second part of predicate:

$(\forall y Q(x,y))$

- $x$ is free, used $v(x)=-2$
- $y$ is bound
- for all $y$ applies, that are equals to -2 -> **false**

$(\forall x R(x,y)) \implies (\forall y Q(x,y)) \iff (0 \implies 0) \iff 1$

Predicate symbol has values: TRUE.

Is that correct?

Comment: The first part seems true for your given values. Thus the implication statement seems false given your values. Intuitively, it seems like it should be false.

Comment: Correct: $False \to False$ is $True$.